# New OneDrive client doesn't sync SharePoint Online libraries with "/" in the title

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I have run into an issue where it seems I cannot sync any document libraries that have a "/" in the title. I know Windows does not support this character in file or folder names, however the previous OneDrive sync client handled this without issue by stripping the illegal characters out and continuing to sync.

When I try to sync one of these libraries, the OneDrive app opens as it should, displaying all folders in the library asking if I want to sync them all. I click "Start Sync" and get an Action Center message saying "your files are syncing here...".  I click the link and get an error message saying the folder cannot be found.  Took me a while to figure out it was the illegal character.  After changing it in the library settings and waiting 30-60 minutes, I can now successfully sync the library.

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find any documentation on how the new sync client handles illegal characters.